# Kitchen Circuits

Tags: electrical, kitchens, circuit

I am redoing a kitchen and have a question regarding circuits.  I have only five 20 amp branch circuits as the box is full and don’t plan on upgrading.  I have two circuits for small appliances outlets (left/right).  I have a dedicated circuit for microwave.  I have a dedicated circuit for a dishwasher.  That leaves me with only one circuit for the fridge and/or garbage disposal.  Which one should I put on the dedicated circuit and which one should I share a circuit with and what circuit.

Comment: To properly answer this question the wattage of the devices is needed and your jurisdiction.

Comment: California.  Fridge is 6a.  Garbage disposal I haven’t purchased yet.

Comment: I'd put it on the microwave circuit unless Code or instructions say you can't. How often do you use both at once?  Also feel free to give yourself a third countertop circuit and have the fridge on that, no chef ever complained of too many.  A typical kitchen heat appliance is 1500W, and 20A circuits only have 2400W, so you can't run 2 per circuit.  Fridges are typically 120W if even that.  Just arrange the GFCIs so the fridge is NOT on GFCI - so nuisance trips don't spoil food.

Comment: Do you know how much current your dishwasher pulls?

Answer (score 2):

With the information available your only safe answer is to provide the disposal a dedicated circuit, and put the fridge on one of the small appliance circuits. The Code says:

> **NEC 210.23(A)(2) Utilization Equipment Fastened in Place**. The total rating of utilization equipment fastened in place, other than
> luminaries, shall not exceed 50-percent of the branch-circuit ampere
> rating where lighting units, cord-and-plug-connected utilization
> equipment not fastened in place, or both, are also supplied.